# How can i Use QList<CustomClass> as QT Meta object

Tags: c++, json, qt, sourceforge, qjson

Hi I am trying to convert the object into JSON. In that process i have created 2 classes.

```
class class1 : Public object
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(QString Item1 READ getItem1 WRITE setItem1)
    Q_PROPERTY(qint64 Item2 READ getItem2 WRITE setItem2)

private:

    QString Item1;
    qint64 Item2;

public:

    QString getItem1 () const { return Item1;}

    void setItem1 (const QString& Item){ Item1= Item; }

// In the same way i have it for item2

}

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(class1*);

Class class2 : public QObject
{

    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(QString Item1 READ getItem1 WRITE setItem1)
    Q_PROPERTY(qint64 Item2 READ getItem2 WRITE setItem2)
    Q_PROPERTY(QList<Class1*> class1List READ getclass1List WRITE setclass1List)

private:
    qint64 Item5;
    qint64 Item6;
    QList< class1* > class1List;

public:

    QString getItem5 () const { return Item5;}

    void setItem5 (const QString& Item){ Item5 = Item; }

    QString getItem6 () const { return Item6;}

    void setItem6 (const QString& Item){ Item6 = Item; }

    const QList<class1*> &getclass1List() const { return class1List;}

    void setclass1List(const QList<class1List*> &List) { class1List= List; }
```

Now i have converted the `class2` object which has `class1` list into `QVariant` using `QJson::QObjectHelper::qobject2qvariant`, All the data inside class2 is converted to JSON, but the list is printed as NULL.

Please let me know what is wrong in this procedure.

I have also tried it with

```
QList<class1*> getclass1List() const { return class1List;}

void setclass1List(const QList<class1List*> List) { class1Lis = List; }
```

But no Use... i am still getting NULL for the value of list in JSON object. If i print the same list as a separate object, i am getting the data.

Comment: Why are you using Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(class1*);? You should just use the class name: Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(class1);

Comment: As i am deriving my class from QObject, the copy constructor is private. SO i am sending its pointer.

I will get this error if i use the object itself
'QObject::QObject(const QObject&)' is private

 @Addy